# How do I use devmil-android-color-picker?

Tags: android, color-picker

I need to use some color picker in my application, so I searched google and found [devmil-android-color-picker](http://code.google.com/p/devmil-android-color-picker/), but I don't understand how to use it in my application. Can someone give me a short example of its usage or suggest a good alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll answer myself =) I connected with author and he helped me with right answer:
Simple example: It works for me:

```
    ColorSelectorDialog dlg = new ColorSelectorDialog(this,
            new ColorSelectorDialog.OnColorChangedListener() {
        public void colorChanged(int color) {
            System.out.println("The new color is: " + color);
        }
    }, colorCurrent);
    dlg.setTitle("Select new color");
    dlg.show();
```